# In reaction equations, why are j and k sometimes capitalized to J and K?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, equilibrium, atmospheric-chemistry, reaction-order

From 'Leighton relationship' on Wikipedia:

through the following mechanism:[2]

($J_1$) $$\ce{NO2 + h\nu (\lambda < 420 nm) → NO + O (^3P)}$$

($k_2$) $$\ce{O (^3P) + O2 + M → O3 + M}$$

($k_3$) $$\ce{NO + O3 → NO2 + O2}$$

This series of reactions creates a null cycle, in which there is no net production or loss of any species involved.

And here:

Since $\ce{O (3P)}$ is very reactive and $\ce{O2}$ is abundant, $\ce{O (3P)}$ can be assumed to be in steady state, and thus an equation linking the concentrations of the species involved can be derived:

$$\ce{[O_3]} = {J_1\ce{[NO2]} \over k_3\ce{[NO]}}$$

$${\displaystyle [{\ce {O3}}]={\frac {J_{1}[{\ce {NO2}}]}{k_{3}[{\ce {NO}}]}}}$$
$${\displaystyle [{\ce {O3}}]={\frac {J_{1}[{\ce {NO2}}]}{k_{3}[{\ce {NO}}]}}}$$

The ${J}$ is capitalized, but the $k$ (or $k$s) are not....

Does this signify anything?

Comment: For eventual writing and formatting of chemical formulas or equations, see how to use [MathJax with mhchem extension](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88)

Comment: Typically lower case k is used for rate constants and upper case K is for equilibrium constants, but I don’t know what j is there

Answer (score 3):

The entry in Wikipedia misses to define the entries in the formula.  But note equations 1 and 2 in a paper by Griffin *et al.* ([doi 10.1029/2006JD007604](https://doi.org/10.1029/2006JD007604), open access) in the Journal of Geophysical Research, Atmospheres. To establish context of the paper by Griffin *et al.*, the authors introduce the reader to the topic citing earlier work.

> «In the troposphere, a molecule of $\ce{NO2}$ is degraded photochemically to form a molecule of $\ce{NO}$ and an oxygen atom ($\ce{O}$). It should be noted that this process depends on the sufficient flux of photons associated with light of the appropriate wavelength to photolyze $\ce{NO2}$. The $\ce{O}$ atom quickly reacts with molecular oxygen ($\ce{O2}$) in the presence of a third body to form $\ce{O3}$. However, the $\ce{O3}$ formed can react rapidly with the $\ce{NO}$ to reform $\ce{NO2}$ and $\ce{O2}$. The net result of these reactions is a null cycle, and when steady state is assumed, the $\ce{O3}$ concentration can be predicted as [Seinfeld and Pandis, 1998]
>
> $$ [\ce{O3}] = \frac{j_\ce{NO2} [\ce{NO2}]} {k_1 [\ce{NO}]}$$
>
> where the bracket notation represents a concentration or mixing ratio (here, parts per billion by volume, ppbv), $j_\ce{NO2}$ ($\pu{s^{-1}}$) is the photolysis rate of $\ce{NO2}$, and $k_1$ ($\pu{ppbv^{-1} s^{-1}}$) is the temperature-dependent rate constant for the reaction between $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{O3}$.»

The article continues by

> «This is referred to as the photostationary state for $\ce{O3}$. If each side of equation (1) is divided by $[\ce{O3}]$, the right hand side is termed the Leighton ratio, $\Phi$ [Leighton, 1961]:
>
> $$\Phi = \frac{j_\ce{NO2} [\ce{NO2}]} {k_1 [\ce{NO}] [\ce{O3}]} $$
> [...]»

Griffin, R. J.; Beckman, P. J.; Talbot, R. W.; Sive, B. C.; Varner, R. K. Deviations from ozone photostationary state during the International Consortium for Atmospheric Research on Transport and Transformation 2004 campaign: Use of measurements and photochemical modeling to assess potential causes. *J. Geophys. Res.* **2007**, *112*, D10S07. [DOI 10.1029/2006JD007604](https://doi.org/10.1029/2006JD007604).